# Is there any way to find the order of destruction of spring singleton beans on shutdown hook?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I am currently trying to find out if there are any undetected or indirect dependencies among my spring beans. I was wondering if there is any way to find out the order of destruction of beans

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Order of bean destruction in Spring context hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35806663/order-of-bean-destruction-in-spring-context-hierarchy)

Comment: Not really. There are several beans being created and implementing preDestroy for all of them might be difficult. I am looking for something similar to BeanPostProcessor but for the shutdown phase

Comment: You asked the same question (more or less) 4 times over the last few days. Please stop asking the same each day. If there is no shutdown hook (predestroy etc) the bean will not be destroyed but just gc'ed.